# Event when machine has been locked/unlocked (Electron Windows)

Tags: node.js, windows, electron

So i have some tasks that i need to be notified when the user locks their machine. This is in order to pause those tasks. Equally i need to know when the machine has been successfully unlocked in order to resume said tasks. This is purely for a Windows only function so doesn't need to be cross-platform.

Ive looked through the Electron docs and found [this](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/power-monitor.md) about the `powerMonitor` API's however it only has events for `suspend` and `resume`. I assume they refer to the machine going to sleep as locking and un-locking does not trigger them on my machine (Win 10).

I know very little of how core Windows works, with its messages/event system. However i have found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383828(VS.85).aspx) which lists information about the `WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE` which seems to be what i need. Notably the `WTS_SESSION_LOCK (0x7)` and `WTS_SESSION_UNLOCK (0x8)` status codes.

However i can't find a way either with electron or NodeJS directly to listen to Windows messages.

Any advice on the problem would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: any luck with solution?

Comment: Afraid not no, i put this down some time ago due to this.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case someone ends up on this old question, [powerMonitor](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/power-monitor) now supports two events for this: `lock-screen` and `unlock-screen`, so you can just (in the main process):

```
const {powerMonitor} = require("electron");

powerMonitor.addListener('lock-screen', () => {
  // Screen is locked, do something
});

powerMonitor.addListener('unlock-screen', () => {
  // Screen is unlocked, do something else
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using 'electron-edge-js'

Here is the solution:

```
if( process.platform == 'win32' || process.platform == 'win64' ) {
    var edge = require( 'electron-edge-js' );

    var checkLockStatus = edge.func( function() {/*
        using System;
        using System.Threading.Tasks;
        using Microsoft.Win32;
        using System.Collections.Generic;

        public class Startup : IDisposable
        {
            private Func<object, Task<object>> callbackFn;
            public async Task<object> Invoke(IDictionary<string, object> input)
            {
                callbackFn = (Func<object, Task<object>>)input["callbackFn"];
                SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += SystemEvents_SessionSwitch;
                return null;

            }

            public async void SystemEvents_SessionSwitch(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
            {
                 if (e.Reason == SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock)
                {
                    callbackFn( "locked" );
                }
                else if (e.Reason == SessionSwitchReason.SessionUnlock)
                {
                   callbackFn( "unlocked" );
                }
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                SystemEvents.SessionSwitch -= SystemEvents_SessionSwitch;
            }
        }
    */} );

    checkLockStatus( {
        callbackFn: function( state ) {
            console.log( state );
        }
    } );
}
```